# Change Response Data in View Results Tree Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I try to make load testing using protobuf protocol. The incoming response has a binary format and not readable in View Result Tree (VRT), kinda:

[image: View Result Tree:]

But I can to convert this hell to the readable format like normal String in the BeanShell PostProcessor.
The question is is there any way to change the information which is showing VRT?
Used prev.setResponseData() and prev.setMessageData() - do not work.

**UPDATE:**

ok it`s work with prev.setMessageData() but the messages is visible on Sampler result tab:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SampleResult.setSamplerData()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setSamplerData(java.lang.String))

Example:

```
prev.setResponseData( decodedString);
prev.setDataType( org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.TEXT );
```